# How can I use jQuery or javascript when I write a post in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

When I put `<script>document.write("<p>JavaScript</p>");</script>`in the post, nothing happened. Why didn't it act like html tags, like`<h1>...</h1>` when we insert them into the post. I examined the output html, It did have the  tag there. Why didn't it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must write HTML or any other scripts in the html Editor. Select the "TEXT" tab on the right top corner of editor and write your code.

Comment: You mean in the "Text" tab? I did.

Comment: Yes in the "Text" tab. @yuhao